# Issue while login to Acumatica 20 R2

Tags: acumatica

am getting this error in 20R2:

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
> compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
> review the following specific error details and modify your source
> code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'PXInternalUseOnlyAttribute'
> exists in both 'PX.Common.Std, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e' and 'PX.Common, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b136cac2f602b8e'

Source Error:

```
Line 12: public class ClientSideAppsHelper
Line 13: {
Line 14:    [PXInternalUseOnly]
Line 15:    private static string GetExternalBandle(string fileName)
Line 16:    {
```

How to resolve this conflict? Running configuration tool did not fix the problem

Comment: Did this happen after an upgrade? Or fresh install?

Comment: Is this an upgrade or a fresh install? Do you have any customisations? As far as I know, this attribute was _moved_ from `PX.Common` to `PX.Common.Std`, so it seems you have an old version of `PX.Common` hanging around.